# Access existing elasticsearch index via spring data

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data

I use spring boot data to access existing index on an elastic search cluster.
In order to create my @Document class representing type , all the below items must be satisfied?

- Index should have a defined mapping.
- All the fields must be included in the class (@Document)
- All the fields must be defined in the right order and with same names.

Thanks

Comment: please add detailed class codes and your works, configurations etc. about this.

Comment: I havent started the project yet. Just need to know if should include all the fields and with exact name as defined in the existing cluster index.